# Subscribe to PointClud2 Ros2

Tags: ros2, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together

I get a depth image from my intel d453 camera in a PointClud2 msgs.
My problem is now the following. I do not understand how I can access the individual points, i.e. XYZ coordinates. It is only possible to access the whole data structure. Unfortunately it is not possible to sort the points correctly.

I need the following information for each point
XYZ coordinates
Color of the point

Is it possible to access the individual points within the data structure in this way?

Here is my Subscriber Callback:

```
void callback_depth_image_d435 (const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr depth_points)
{
 
  printf("Cloud: width = %u, height = %u\n", depth_points->width, depth_points->height);

 // Looking for Something like that
 //      BOOST_FOREACH(const Point& pt, depth_points->points)
 //      {
 //        printf("\tpos = (%f, %f, %f), w = %u, normal = (%f, %f, %f)\n",
 //               pt.pos.x, pt.pos.y, pt.pos.z, pt.w,
 //                 pt.normal[0], pt.normal[1], pt.normal[2]);
 //      }

  //test
  std::cout << "data_size" << depth_points->data.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "point_step" << depth_points->point_step << "\n";
  //std::cout << "data_size" << depth_points-> << "\n";
  std::cout << "data_size" << depth_points->data.size() << "\n";
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368218/subscribe-to-pointclud2-ros2/) by [Schloern93](https://answers.ros.org/users/64641/schloern93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a solution.

1. Install pcl_conversion (sudo apt install ros-eloquent-pcl-conversions)

CMakeList

```
    find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
    target_link_libraries("target" ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Subscriber Callback

```
 void callback_depth_image_d435 (const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr point_cloud2_msgs)
 {

   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> point_cloud;
   pcl::fromROSMsg(*point_cloud2_msgs, point_cloud);     

   BOOST_FOREACH(const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, point_cloud.points)
   {          
       std::cout  << "x: " << pt.x <<"\n";
       std::cout  << "y: " << pt.y <<"\n";
       std::cout  << "z: " << pt.z <<"\n";
       std::cout << "---------" << "\n";
   }
 }
```

---

Originally posted by [Schloern93](https://answers.ros.org/users/64641/schloern93/) with karma: 51 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimoneBenatti](https://answers.ros.org/users/71643/simonebenatti/) on 2021-04-06**:
I tried the inverse procedure (feeding data to pointcloud2) on Eloquent but I'm stuck since toROSMsg expects  pcl::PointCloud and pcl::PCLPointCloud2. This is the one defined in pcl/ros/conversions.h